# Access to class from class which is property

Tags: typescript, es6-class

I'm doing multiplayer game in canvas using Typescript. I have a player class which property is a class with player statistics and equipment class.

```
class Player {
    statistics = new Stats()
    eq = new Equipment()
}

class Stats {
    strength = 3
    ...
}
class Equipment {
    'items which have parameters like +3 strength etc.'
}
```

So I have base statistics from Stats and additional statistics from Equipment and I need to combine them, but Player class mostly describes informations about player position in 2d world, on which map is he, image etc. Should I put method which combines statistics in Player class? Is it allowed to export class instance via ES6 import to another class and use it there? What if i need to get one of player property in stats or equipment? Should I pass player to constructor?

Comment: I believe you should first to write it as You think and then go back to stackoverflow with your code examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally normal to have an instance of a class as a property of another class.

> What if I need to get one of player property in stats or equipment? Should I pass player to constructor?

Passing an instance of another class into a class constructor is also totally normal.  However I would advise against bi-directional relationships.  A `Player` has `Equipment` OR `Equipment` has a `Player`, but I would not do both.  If you need to get some piece of information which depends on both class instances, you would get that from the one which `has` the other.  Based on your code above, that would be the `Player`.

For example, if you want to get a specific stat `defense` where we take the player's base defense add some boost from the equipment, that might look like this:

```
getDefense(): number {
    return this.statistics.defense + this.equipment.stats.defense;
}
```

Maybe we don't want to have to create a method for each individual stat, so we could create a general method that gets a stat by name. We use `keyof Stats` as a way to ensure that all name strings are valid.

```
class Player {
    private statistics: Stats;
    private eq: Equipment;

    constructor( baseStats: Stats, equipment: Equipment ) {
        this.statistics = baseStats;
        this.eq = equipment;
    }

    public changeEquipment( equipment: Equipment ): void {
        this.eq = equipment;
    }

    public getStat( name: keyof Stats ): number {
        return this.statistics[name] + this.eq.stats[name];
    }
}
```

Another thing we can do is expose the stats as a `public readonly` property. That's what I've done in `Equipment`.  We don't want the stats to be edited from outside of the class, but we can't just make the property `readonly` because we want to be able to edit the stats when calling `levelUp()`.

You can have both public and private versions of a variable, using `_` to prefix the private version, so that data can be publicly readable but is only editable within the class.  The only way to edit it from outside is through calling class methods.

```
class Equipment {
    
    private _stats: Stats;
    public readonly name: string;

    constructor( name: string, baseStats: Stats ) {
        this.name = name;
        this._stats = baseStats;
    }

    /**
     * readonly public accessor
     */
    get stats(): Stats {
        return this._stats;
    }

    /**
     * increase all stats by 1
     */
    levelUp(): void {
        Object.keys(this._stats).forEach( key => {
            this._stats[key as keyof Stats] += 1;
        })
    }
}
```

Based on the way you've described `Stats`, I think it should just be an `interface` rather than a `class` since it's just a bunch of numbers.  Use classes when you want to have methods, or when you have properties which depend on each other.

```
interface Stats {
    strength: number;
    defense: number;
    hp: number;
}
```

But if you wanted to have a class that implements that interface, so could pass in instance of that class to the constructor of either `Player` or `Equipment` and there would be no issue.  That flexibility makes good design.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjmAzsg3gWAChkTkswoIQBzMACwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuI05ACYQYVLBCatOPPqToAHCey5RehAL5EiCADZwsOAKIBHFsDlsqYPDJI3kcqMABumFAH1ymLE3RfV-ORYObWAEZEo4AQB7EG0AT2Y4CyZyRxpVOwQY1JYEMCioAApE5LIKUGoAGmQOPQhfbB8MbGQASmtiflJ6YCwAOhAklABeEoh-LpIe-o9mnFHasQasCZINQjsAegAqbbtkbfCISJj4%20yCQsMQkfQL97c27aggrT2xC1qavDsmSSjAWFAQMhpn1Zn47Ostrt7shQAgImJkHBtNoyt8OAkAIz3R6dEjaCBOCDaACqcg%20TCcUWAAh%20vwA8hwAFYQPJ9ADWEDiWEKoPB2FafRgBQMiDoxS5CWGAD56b9unRemC3lgANpS5E4KVRGBoOYAXWQAGpRljVl01K1IUQoYQdHocAAFXRxaDy%20yOFyQdFgXp%20hDefUQ-Ge5yuZAQIxMYymcyWDKhrIgHJ5ArFRb1OZfbDVKNxizgGMmMyFqztAih-igt7%200LzGp1ZYW6tK-pR5CjfOlhM2jahwLBULIBB0OA0CCxnvgYrd%20NF5BT%20flqk0umVhWgjtdkvLi12gIXYfPMANYqDUo6vXLNqKKRQD38f6A4E15p1wNqi8QI3GkFtvooz6VUvyGA191tIA)